# Mediawiki 1.26.2 upgrade - categories listed in a single column

Tags: mediawiki

I upgraded two mediawiki sites from 1.24.1 to 1.26.2 today.  The first one [appears to be working fine](http://gz.equoria.net/Category:Everquest_II), but the second one has developed an interesting anomaly.  Categories and Sub-Categories are consistently [listed in a single column](http://sysadm.equoria.com/index.php/Category:User_Applications).  Unfortunately, I haven't found anyplace where this is supposed to be controllable.  It sure would be nice to get things back to normal.

MediaWiki 1.26.2, PHP 5.5.31 (cgi-fcgi), MySQL 5.5.40-36.1-log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some kind of Google Analytics plugin is messing up asset loading so the multicolumn CSS never gets loaded: http://sysadm.equoria.com/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=startup&only=scripts&skin=monobook

Comment: You nailed it is one!   It is an old Google Analytics include that, unfortunately doesn't have any internal documentation.  But my notes say it was installed in April of last year.  Commented it out and everything is working.  That is an interesting trick you used.  Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I just looked at the error messages in the [Chrome browser console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en#opening-the-console) and it indicated this URL.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you very much for your help.  That include was buried in an odd location, so it would have taken me ages to discover.  Thanks again!